# How to edit search term format in Search Landing Page title

Tags: magento2.3

Is there a way to edit serach term format in search landing page title.

For example, how to change from: `SEARCH RESULTS FOR TEST` to: `SEARCH RESULTS FOR "TEST"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Magento already has a single quote appended to the search term. Like:

[image]

However, if you wish to change it, you can add a translation string to the en_US.csv file and add the below strings

> Search results for: '%1'

**Translate to**

> Search results for "%1"

Or If the above doesn't work, you can also create a preference or plugin of the class, **\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result** and modify the method **getSearchQueryText**

**From**:

```
/**
     * Get search query text
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getSearchQueryText()
    {
        return __("Search results for: '%1'", $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText());
    }
```

**To**

```
/**
     * Get search query text
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getSearchQueryText()
    {
        return __('Search results for: "%1"', $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText());
    }
```

**Result**:

[image]